# YII2 add horizontal scrollbar in gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, horizontal-scrolling, yii-widgets

I have a database table with 32 columns and I successfully displayed them in the yii2 gridview. The problem is the 32 columns will not fit in the window. I want to add a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom. How can I do that?

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put a div around it and then set the overflow using CSS. You will need to set the height.

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
Height:?
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 you can always use `table-responsive` class like so;

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <?= GridView::widget(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using kartik, just add :

```
'options' => ['style' => ['width' => '1800px']]
```

include resize font :

```
'options' => ['style' => ['font-size'=>'13px', 'width' => '1800px']],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add div around GridView:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; width: 100%;">
     <?= GridView::widget...?>
</div>
```